# unable to update list using LINQ

Tags: c#

**Why it's unable to update item value based on a condition using LINQ 
Here is my code :**

```
class Program
{
    public static List<Items> items = new List<Items>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        // Add items to list
        for (int i = 65; i <= 70 ; i++)
        {
        var RowItem = new Items();
            RowItem.Code = i;
            RowItem.Char = (char)(i);
            items.Add(RowItem);
        }


        //Update item
        items
            .Where(s => s.Code == 70)
            .Select(s => { s.Char ='*' ; return s; })
            .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t " + item.Code + " ----> " + item.Char);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Item class defined as below
Item class defined as below
Item class defined as belowItem class defined as below

```
public class Items
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public Char Char { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: An assignment is missing, it seems.

Comment: `items = items.Where...`

Comment: This is your condition `for (int i = 65; i <= 70 ; i++)` and you are doing a where like this `.Where(s => s.Code == 700)`. Your values are between 65 and 70

Comment: @Dani that 700 should be read as 70

Comment: Why do so many people think it´s a good idea to *update* with the so-called language-integrated **query**-technic? It´s not, linq isn´t ment to be used for updates. However you can of course create a new list based upon your existing one.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     //Update item
>     items
>         .Where(s => s.Code == 700)
>         .Select(s => { s.Char ='*' ; return s; })
>         .ToList();
> ```

You do not update anything. You just create a temporary list and then **discard the result**, because it is not assigned to anything.

Note that `Items` is a value type and cannot be effected by modifying the *local copy* of it in the lambda function.

Comment: (Now seen the bottom bit, which is the most important part...)